# RxJS subscribe inside subscribe with actions on error

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

I have code with `subscribe` inside `subscribe`:

```
this.http.post('/update1', newData).subscribe(
    (response) => {
        const r = response.json;
        const id = r['id'];
        this.http.post('/update2?id=' + id, newData).subscribe(
            () => {
                this.http.post('/update3?id=' + id, newData).subscribe(
                    () => {
                        console.log('success');
                    },
                    () => {
                        // revert changes made to update2
                        this.http.post('/update2', previousValues).subscribe();
                        // revert changes made to update1
                        this.http.post('/update1', previousValues).subscribe();
                    });
            },
            () => {
                // revert changes made to update1
                this.http.post('/update1', previousValues).subscribe();
            }
        );
    },
    (error) => {
        console.log(error);
    }
);
```

How can I optimize it in RxJS 5?

Comment: Use `mergeMap` or `concatMap` instead of the first `subscribe`

Comment: What goga said ... you should never need to nest subscriptions. This might help you: https://blog.strongbrew.io/rxjs-best-practices-in-angular/

Answer (score 4):

**Please don't use subscribe inside another subscribe.** Using native RxJS operators, there is better way around this which will be:

```
this.http
  .post('/update1', newData)
  .pipe(
    map((response) => response.json),
    map((data) => data.id),
    switchMap((id) =>
      this.http.post('/update2?id=' + id, newData).pipe(
        switchMap(() => this.http.post('/update3?id=' + id, newData)),
        catchError((err) => {
          // this catcherror will happen if update3 failes
          return merge(
            // revert changes made to update2
            this.http.post('/update2', previousValues),
            // revert changes made to update1
            this.http.post('/update1', previousValues),
          );
        }),
      ),
    ),
    catchError((err) => {
      // this catcherror will happen if update2 failes
      // revert changes made to update1
      return this.http.post('/update1', previousValues);
    }),
  )
  .subscribe(
    (result) => {
      console.log(result);
    },
    (err) => {
      // this error will happen if an error happens wich is not caught
      console.log(err);
    },
  );
```

**This way you only have one subscribe method** to handle last remaining result if you want to.

Keep in mind that `catchError()` inside pipe will be trigerred if exception is fired prior to it anywhere. If exception is handled already, by the handler, same exact exception will not trigger other `catchError()` twice.