# How can I improve my Angular component so that I am using switchMap instead of chaining multiple subscriptions?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm making use of RxJS and observables within my Angular application to process the results of API calls and process data. I've written the component and it works without any issues. However after further research into RxJS and observables I've became aware that the way in which I am using subscriptions is considered bad practice.

Essentially I have a function that subscribes to an observable, then inside the subscription a second function is called which doesn't make use of the data from the first subscription, but subscribes to a separate observable to track the state of a particular variable. Then within the same function a third method is called which does make use of data passed from the first subscription and uses it to make an API call and return some data.

What I want to do is refactor this code so that the same behaviour occurs but so that I am making use of `switchMap` or other RxJS functions so that the bad practice within my code is removed. However I am unsure as to how I should be employing the use of switchMap etc.

I'll post my code below with each function I have described and annotated.

```
initSettings(){
    this.getOrganisations$().subscribe( (res: AdminOrganisation[]) => {  //This is the first subscription that makes a get request to return an array of AdminOrganisation objects
      this.organisations = res;                                          //this results of this subscription are used to display different input options to the user in the form of
      this.serial = this.organisations[0].serialRef;                     //a mat-list.
      this.currentOrganisationName = this.organisations[0].serialName;
      this.buildSettingsForm(this.serial);
    });
  }

  buildSettingsForm(serial: string) {
    this.ipRangeFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group(
        {
          ipRanges: this.formBuilder.array([])
        }
    );

    this.numArrayElements = this.ipRangeFormArray.length;

    this.ipRangeFormArray.valueChanges.subscribe(changes => {           //This is the second subscription, this one does not require any external inputs but does rely on the 
      this.numArrayElements = this.ipRangeFormArray.length;             //this.ipRangeFormArray being instantiated before it can be called, therefore it has to be create 
    });                                                                 //syncronously and after the first subscription has recieved and utilised data.

    this.setSettings(serial);
  }

  setSettings(serial: string) {                                                     //This is the third subscription, this subscription utilises the this.serial variable that
    this.getSettingsFromSerial$(serial).subscribe(val => {                          //is retrieved by the first subscription and therefore relies on the data from the first
      this.savedSettingsState = val;                                                //observable to function. Like the second sub, this one also needs to occur after the first
      this.ipRestrictionEnabled = val.ipRestrictionSettings.ipRestrictionEnabled;   //has processed its data.
      for (const i of val.ipRestrictionSettings.ipRanges) {
        this.addRange(i.startRange, i.endRange, i.label);
      }
      this.displayForm = true;
    });
  }
```

Once I have a grasp on how I should be utilising switchMap/mergeMap/etc I'll be more confident in making this refactorings and improvements myself. But since I am relatively new to Angular I'm unsure as to what the best practice is when making use of these functions to prevent chains of subscriptions like what I have below.

Comment: Here is an example of how you can use switchMap (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55447803/angular-subscribe-within-subscribe/55447947#55447947)

Answer (score 0):

With the smallest amount of changes, something like this:

```
initSettings() {
  this.getOrganisations$().pipe(
    switchMap((res: AdminOrganisation[]) => {
      this.organisations = res;
      this.serial = this.organisations[0].serialRef;
      this.currentOrganisationName = this.organisations[0].serialName;
      return this.buildSettingsForm(this.serial);
    })
  ).subscribe();
}

buildSettingsForm(serial: string) {
  this.ipRangeFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group(
    {
      ipRanges: this.formBuilder.array([])
    }
  );

  this.numArrayElements = this.ipRangeFormArray.length;

  return merge(
    this.ipRangeFormArray.valueChanges.pipe(
      tap(_ => {
        this.numArrayElements = this.ipRangeFormArray.length;
      })
    ),
    this.setSettings(serial)
  );
}

setSettings(serial: string) {
  return this.getSettingsFromSerial$(serial).pipe(
    tap(val => {
      this.savedSettingsState = val;
      this.ipRestrictionEnabled = val.ipRestrictionSettings.ipRestrictionEnabled;
      for (const i of val.ipRestrictionSettings.ipRanges) {
        this.addRange(i.startRange, i.endRange, i.label);
      }
      this.displayForm = true;
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: So I've just tried to implement your code and I seem to be getting a compiler error. Any ideas? `TS2345: Argument of type '(res: AdminOrganisation[]) => OperatorFunction<{}, any>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: AdminOrganisation[], index: number) => ObservableInput<{}>'.`

Comment: @Jake12342134 make sure you import `merge` from `rxjs`, not from `rxjs/operators`

Comment: That was it, thank you. What's the difference between the two imports?

Comment: One is an operator (used in pipes), the other one merges events from observables and returns an observable.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks. Unfortunately now my code has a lot of bugs that weren't present from the refactoring.

Comment: @Jake12342134 Feel free to upvote and mark the response as answer.

Comment: My code now has bugs and no longer works as desired. Why would I upvote or mark your answer as correct?

Comment: @Jake12342134 are you sure the bugs are introduced by this change? It should behave pretty much the same... (except before you didn't destroy subscriptions, which now you do if there are no more elements - so you probably need exhaustMap instead of switchMap).

Comment: If I comment your code and uncomment my old code the app works as expected. It's strange because there are certain behaviours that are now bugged that I wouldn't expect to be bugged by this change. But this code is the only thing I've changed so it must be causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's only call to this.getOrganisations$, make a switchMap. inside the switchMap use teh response and add at the end return this.getSettingsFromSerial$. so, in subscribe you has the response of the last observable, some like: -I'm not checked the parenthesis-

```
initSettings(){
    this.getOrganisations$().pipe(switchMap((res: AdminOrganisation[]) => {  
      //make something with res
      this.organisations = res;                                          
      this.serial = this.organisations[0].serialRef;                     
      this.currentOrganisationName = this.organisations[0].serialName;
      this.buildSettingsForm(this.serial);
      //but return the last observable
      return this.getSettingsFromSerial$(this.serial)
    }))).subscribe(val => {                          
      this.savedSettingsState = val; 
      this.ipRestrictionEnabled = val.ipRestrictionSettings.ipRestrictionEnabled;   
      for (const i of val.ipRestrictionSettings.ipRanges) {
        this.addRange(i.startRange, i.endRange, i.label);
      }
      this.displayForm = true;
    });
  }
  }

  //buildSettingsFrom dont need any thing but serial, and don't call to 
  //setSettings, that you remove

  buildSettingsForm(serial: string) {
    this.ipRangeFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group(
        {
          ipRanges: this.formBuilder.array([])
        }
    );

    this.numArrayElements = this.ipRangeFormArray.length;

    this.ipRangeFormArray.valueChanges.subscribe(changes => {           
      this.numArrayElements = this.ipRangeFormArray.length;             
    });                                                                 
  }
```