# There's a more elegantly way to combine two simultaneous requests better than inside subscribe?

Tags: angular, request

maybe someone can improve it using RxJs operators, but i have no idea, because i need the value of the first request:

```
adicionarUnidade() {

this.restApi.createUnidade(this.unidadeDetalhes).subscribe((res: Unidade) => {

  this.unidadeResponseArr = res;
  this.unidadeUsuarioDetalhes.unidadeId = this.unidadeResponseArr.data.id;

  for (let i = 0; i < this.unidadeUsuarioArr.length; i++) {
    this.unidadeUsuarioDetalhes.usuarioId = this.unidadeUsuarioArr[i].id;

    this.restApi.createUnidadeUsuario(this.unidadeUsuarioDetalhes).subscribe(() => {

     this.router.navigate(['/unidade/lista-de-unidades']);
    });
  }
});
```

}

Comment: What is this doing? Create unit, loop, create user and navigate inside the loop?

Comment: first it's create the unity, then with the value of the unity to add the users to that unity

Comment: yes but why the navigate inside the loop? and can you modify the back-end? One request with a set of Ids and add them all

Comment: I am surprised this is working for you currently. The navigate not being run before you have finished looping over the array... Must be a very small array? If you want to send multiple requests in parallel you should take a look at the mergeMap operator in RXJS library, you can create multiple observables and merge them into one to send at once, then subscribe to the completion of call before navigating.

Comment: @Sam It can't work. Such nested subscriptions doesn't work

Comment: You shouldn't use nested subscribes. Check out operators like mergeMap, switchMap, combine etc on how to do it correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular Subscribe within Subscribe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55447803/angular-subscribe-within-subscribe)

Comment: for your surprise its working perfectly but i know that there's some operators who i can use to improve it