# Avoid nested subscribing when you don't want the outer subscribe to complete, and the inner should complete

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an Angular material menu with sub-menu panels.
It's in a file manager app, and there is a context menu for the files, which has an option to "Move to" a folder:

[image]

I an trying to make clicking a middle level panel also close the entire menu (this is not the default behavior).

To do that, i wrote this function:

```
 private handleClosingOptionsMenuWhenMovingFiles() {
    this.actionsMenuOpened$.pipe(
      untilComponentDestroyed(this)
    ).subscribe(() => {
      this.documentsTabDetailsService.moveToFolderEvent$.pipe(
        takeUntil(this.contextMenuTrigger.menuClosed),
      ).subscribe(
        () => this.contextMenuTrigger.closeMenu(),
        () => { },
        () => console.log(' COMPLETED'));
    });
  }
```

It works great, but it's using ugly nested subscribes, and i can't figure out how to convert it to a single pipe with operators, and only one subscribe at the end.

The issue is that the actionsMenuOpened$ should still be subscribed to, because the user may open the menu again, but the inner stream of moveToFolderEvent$ should complete each time the  menu is closed.

Any idea?

Comment: you can make use of rxjs operators like `switchMap`. I have an example at this post :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/55447947/10959940

Answer (score 1):

please use `flatmap` along with `pipe`, try this

```
this.actionsMenuOpened(...)
  .pipe(
    flatMap(success => this.documentsTabDetailsService.moveToFolderEvent(...)),
  )
  .subscribe(success => {(...)});
```

please check more details about `flatmap` here http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html

Comment: Thanks! I changed it to:  `this.actionsMenuOpened$.pipe(
      untilComponentDestroyed(this),
      flatMap(() => this.documentsTabDetailsService.moveToFolderEvent$),
      takeUntil(this.contextMenuTrigger.menuClosed),
    ).subscribe(
      () => this.contextMenuTrigger.closeMenu(),
      () => { },
      () => console.log(' COMPLETED')
    );` but i never see the COMPLETED log when navigating to another page. Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I finally decided to go with another approach:

```
    this.documentsTabDetailsService.moveToFolderEvent$.pipe(
      untilComponentDestroyed(this))
      .subscribe(
        () => {
          if (this.contextMenuTrigger.menuOpen) {
            this.contextMenuTrigger.closeMenu();
          }
        }, err => { },
        () => console.log('COMPLETED')
      );
```

It subscribes, and stays subscribed, to the event that fires when moving an item.
I am not sure if which is better in terms of performance (maybe i'm now keeping an open subscription for longer).