# Wait for another observable to complete with await

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

Hi all In my angular app I have two methods getA and getB. I've added third one getC that is dependent on results from getB. How can I wait for getB to complete ? I want to use this.B variable in getC method.

```
 async ngOnInit() {
      await getA();
      await getB();
      await getC();
 }

getA(): void {
  this.service.fetchA(this.id)
     .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
        .subscribe((res) => {
            {
                this.A = res;
            }
        });

}

getB(): void {
  this.service.fetchB(this.id)
       .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
           .subscribe((res) => {
              this.B = res;
           });
}

getC(): void{
  this.service.fetchC(this.id).subscribe((res) => {
      this.C = this.B + something;
   });
}
```

Comment: does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55447803/angular-subscribe-within-subscribe

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```
async ngOnInit() {
      getA();
      getB();
 }

getA()....

getB(): void {
  this.service.fetchB(this.id)
       .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
           .subscribe((res) => {
              this.B = res;
              this.getC();
           });
}

getC()....
```

Comment: getB() method is used in another places as well, I know that it will work but need another solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell how your services work.
If these are http requests you do not need unsubscribe. If A is irrelevant, then simple switchMap will do the trick:

```
this.service.fetchB().pipe(
  switchMap((serviceBresult:resultBtype) => 
    this.service.fetchC(serviceBresult)
  ),
  tap((serviceCResult:'resultCtype') => console.log(serviceCResult))
).subscribe()
```

Comment: I can't change service methods because they are used in other places. All of them are simple http get requests.